# Camera.takePicture() - проблема

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Метод `Camera.takePicture(...)` работает только при нажатии на кнопку, а мне надо сделать так, чтобы в AsyncTask камера делала фотографию и сохраняла её каждые 5 минут. Пробовал так и не получилось:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    while (true) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                try {
                    file = new File(dir, "test.jpg");
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    outputStream.write(data);
                    outputStream.close();
                    publishProgress();
                } catch (IOException e1) {}
            }
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть у меня получается делать снимок только по нажатию по кнопке.